# make error: Circular filex <- filey dependency dropped

Tags: makefile

I am copying two types of inputs **(.y and .yuv)** from server using `make` file target.
I Wants to copy gray images and yuv images at **../input** folder from server location.

```
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
# Gray scale images
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH = ../input
VID_INPUT_GRAYIMG_FILES =   \
    inputGray0.y    \
    inputGray1.y
VID_INPUTGRAY = $(addprefix $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/, $(VID_INPUT_GRAYIMG_FILES))
VID_INPUTGRAY_NOCLEAN = $(addprefix -e , $(VID_INPUTGRAY))

vpath %.y server:/stddataset/ped server:/stddataset/car

.PRECIOUS: $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%
$(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/% : %
    mkdir -p $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)
    scp server:$^ $@

#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
# YUV images
#++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++#
VID_INPUT_YUV_FILES =   \
    inputYuv0.yuv \
    inputYuv1.yuv \
    inputYuv2.yuv \
    inputYuv3.yuv   
VID_INPUT_YUV = $(addprefix $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/, $(VID_INPUT_YUV_FILES))
VID_INPUT_NOCLEAN = $(addprefix -e , $(VID_INPUT_YUV))

$(VID_INPUT_YUV) : $(VID_INPUTGRAY) $(VID_INPUT_YUV) 

.PRECIOUS: $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%.yuv
$(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/%.yuv : 
    mkdir -p $(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)
    scp server:/stddataset/crowd/yuv/$(notdir $@) $@
```

**Error:**

```
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv0.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv0.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv1.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv0.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv1.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv1.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv2.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv0.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv2.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv1.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv2.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv2.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv3.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv0.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv3.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv1.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv3.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv2.yuv dependency dropped.
make: Circular ../input/ inputYuv3.yuv <- ../input/ inputYuv3.yuv dependency dropped.
```

**How to resolve this circular dependency.**

Comment: I don't understand how you can list a prerequisite of `%.yuv` here, when your rules are copying files from another system.  The prerequisite of a target has to be a file that exists or that make can build.  Make doesn't know how to go look at the contents of some other host to find its prerequisite.  I don't think you can add prerequisites to these `scp` rules and have it make sense.

Comment: @MadScientist, That is my mistake.But by removing the prerequisite also, I am still having this circular dependency. I tied using the macro **$(VID_INPUT_YUV) : $(VID_INPUTGRAY) $(VID_INPUT_YUV)** which store just first macro definitions  which is VID_INPUTGRAY. The above target just copying only *.y or *.yuv input. Not BOTH.

Comment: @MadScientist, I have corrected my make file after your reply. But still the problem persists.

Comment: You only corrected one of them.  You still have the other: `$(VID_INPUT_YUV_PATH)/% : %`  In general it's problematic to use a "match-anything" target or prerequisite: just `%`.  That tells make that ANY file can match.  It's very likely to create circular dependencies.

Comment: The rule `$(VID_INPUT_YUV) : $(VID_INPUTGRAY) $(VID_INPUT_YUV)` says that every target in the list to which `$(VID_INPUT_YUV)` expands depends on (among other things) every target in the list to which `$(VID_INPUT_YUV)` exands, which includes itself.  This produces circular dependencies.  It's not clear to me what you actually intend here.

Comment: Also, you have what appears to be unwanted space characters around the commas in your `$(addprefix)` calls.  Those spaces are *significant*.  You can see some of the effects of that in the error messages presented.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, '$(VID_INPUT_YUV) : $(VID_INPUTGRAY) $(VID_INPUT_YUV)' ..Here I want to set 'VID_INPUTGRAY' and 'VID_INPUT_YUV' list into 'VID_INPUT_YUV' . Wants to do like set(a $a $b) in cmake.

Comment: If you want to assign a value to a variable then use an assignment statement (`VID_INPUT_YUV = ...`).  But it would be clearer in this case to use a different name for the variable containing the combined list, maybe`VID_INPUTS` or similar.

Comment: let me check this. I will update the answer afterwards.